# display array parsed from ini as html table?

Tags: php, html, ini

I'm trying to create a table of info about mods in a pack for a game server,
I can parse the INI but can't figure out how to place it into an html table properly.
the ini is:

```
[industrialcraft]
name = IndustrialCraft²
dev = Alblaka
website = http://www.industrial-craft.net
wiki = industrialcraft
[buildcraft]
name = BuildCraft
dev = SirSengir
website = http://www.mod-buildcraft.com/
wiki = buildcraft
```

I'm trying to get it into columns for the dev,website,etc. with headers at the top (name section doesn't need the header). and the wiki one is going to link to domain.com/wiki/bunchofstuff?id=insert_here
I want it to look sort of like this:

```
                |   Dev   |         Official Website        |   Wiki Page
IndustrialCraft | Alblaka | http://www.industrial-craft.net | wiki link
```

I can manage the layout myself, but I figured I should specify in case it affects how it needs to be coded.
I've been trying to figure it out myself but I'm still a bit of a noob with php..

Comment: checked http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-ini-file.php yet?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, I was just about to fix that format haha

Comment: @conceptdeluxe Yes, but thanks. I can parse the ini, I should have specified I need help getting it into a table. edited my question.

Comment: then may check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010082/generating-html-table-from-php-array ... :)

Comment: @conceptdeluxe that does help, thanks, but I still need to get the data from the parsed INI. I tried echoing and printing $ini_array[industrialcraft] with no luck :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was that really hard?

```
<?php
  $datas  = parse_ini_file( $ini_file, true );
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <?php
      foreach( $datas as $data ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["name"] ); ?></td>
      <td>Dev</td>
      <td>Official Website</td>
      <td>Wiki Page</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["dev"] ); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["website"] ); ?></td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://domain.com/wiki/bunchofstuff?id=<?php echo urlencode( $data["wiki"] ); ?>">wiki link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```